# Dataframe has no attribute label

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn

So I am making a decision tree based of spotify top 100. When I try and set Y as my target variable I get line 5179, in `__getattr__`

```
return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'label' 

col_names = [
  'id',
  'name',
  'artists',
  'danceability',
  'energy',
  'key',
  'loudness',
  'mode',
  'speechiness',
  'acousticness',
  'instrumentalness',
  'liveness',
  'valence',
  'tempo',
  'duration_ms',
  'time_signature'
]

df = pd.read_csv("top2018.csv")
# print(df)

feature_cols = [
  'id',
  'name',
  'artists',
  'danceability',
  'energy',
  'key',
  'loudness',
  'mode',
  'speechiness',
  'acousticness',
  'instrumentalness',
  'liveness',
  'valence',
  'tempo',
  'duration_ms',
  'time_signature'
]

X = df[feature_cols]
Y = df.label()
```

Am i getting the right featured columns? why am I getting that attribute error back?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what your label is. If you want the 'energy' column to be your target, you can use

```
Y = df['energy']
```

Let me know if this is what you are asking or if I missed the point here.

Answer (score 0):

The error massage is quite clear:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'label'

Your dataframe object: `df`, does not have the called attribute `df.label()`

You have to assign the label to it:

```
Y = df['columnname']
```